# Haworth structures of sucrose and lactose

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, carbohydrates

The haworth structures of lactose and sucrose  is

[image]

[image]

My question is regarding the glyosidic linkage, in lactose it is represented as a zig zag and in sucrose it is a "V". What does that mean. Also, in sucrose why is the the glyosidic linkage displaced down w.r.t the compound

Comment: The link in lactose structure is beta (up position)-1(1-position around the ring)-4(glucose's 4-position around its ring, in which the OH is down for glucose). The link in sucrose is alpha (down)-1(glucose's 1-position)-2(fructose's 2-position which is at the down position because fructose is "facing" the glucose unit and it is upside down).

Comment: Haworth structures are cumbersome to draw in this regard. The bridging oxygens are attached directly to the rings and not to CH2 groups as the "zig-zag" and "V" might imply.